# make my divs fade in/out on a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have basic code setup to make divs slide in but i want to change it to a fade.
I would like it model after this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XAyL3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XAyL3/8/)?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.hidden').fadeOut("fast");
      $(this).next('.hidden').fadeIn("slow");
  });
    $('.hidden:first').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: yea but i want the text to show up in the middle of the screen like center aligned

Comment: @user3182229 That's a matter of CSS, not of jQuery. See my edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XAyL3/8/